# Parametrization of all unimodular matrices of rank $n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integer-lattices, unimodular-matrices

For a given rank $n$, are there parametrization families that cover  all possible unimodular matrices of rank $n$?

For example for $n=3$ Wolfram gives an example of one [parametrization family](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnimodularMatrix.html).

Comment: What are the properties do you want explicitly and what have you tried? Of course $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
c & 1/d \end{pmatrix}$$ where $d = a^{-1}(\pm 1+bc)$ is a parametrization.

Comment: The example of Wolfram doesn't cover all unimodular matrices, but it's given by integer polynomials. It seems that you want to give a family of polynomials $P_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Z}[m]$ such that $det(P_{i j}[x]) = 1$ and they cover all of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ or $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ when evaluated on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez that is correct.

Comment: You should modify the title and question to make that clear, then.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez the title is clear. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should specify that you want a parametrization by polynomials and what exactly are the properties that you want from those polynomials. I have reverse-engineered your question's statement.

Comment: I should mention, the parametrization should strictly over the integers and necessarily restricted to polynomials, exponential or combinatorial formulas are good too, or a mix of those.